# How to reference a private repository in Git HUb enterprise in package.json?

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I've a private repository hosted on git hub enterprise. I want to download this package for my app. How do I reference this in my package.json?

Comment: Do you have ssh keys setup?

Answer (score 0):

```
"repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/username/your-project.git"
}
```